# Remove tuples from a dictionary and return a new dict with the N most frequent words

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So i have a dictionary object containing over 10k words, these words are already counted. For example: "away: 128". The tricky part for me is finding the N(dynamic) most frequent words in this dictionary whilst also excluding seperate lists of strings from the N most frequent words.
def getMostFrequent():

```
exclWordList = tuple(englConj), tuple(englPrep), tuple(englPronouns), tuple(specialWords)
topNumber = 10

topFreqWords =  dict(sorted(Counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[topNumber])
tfw = {}
i=1
for item in topFreqWords:
    for ew in exclWordList:
        if ew not in topFreqWords:
                tfw[item] = i
                i += 1

return tfw
```

The N most frequent words have to be returned as a dictionary as well, where the number of keys is the same as what i input as N.

Any ideas? I have tried some solutions but nothing i tried came close to working, any ideas?

Comment: Please share your previous attempts, as well as the expected output for certain test data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want, assuming `counted` is the name of your dictionary:

```
dict(sorted(counted.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:N])
```

This sorts descending by count (which is the second item of each key-value tuple in `counted.items()`) and returns the first `N` items as a `list` of `tuple`s.  Passing the result to `dict` will turn the list of tuples into a dictionary.